# Should I include details about extracurricular art projects on a grad program application?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I'm in the process of applying to graduate programs in a field unrelated to music. I write, record, and perform original music in my free time. Normally I would not mention this in a personal statement; however, one of the programs I am applying to has an additional statement where I am to discuss ways in which I would add to the diversity of the school. I do have material I hope to discuss that falls within normal parameters of relevance, but I am wondering if it would also be appropriate (or rather, not obviously inappropriate) to mention my creative projects? I would obviously attempt to mention them in a way that demonstrates personality traits about me (creativity and drive), rather than just an irrelevant aside.

Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if there's any additional info I can provide.

Comment: Normally I'd vote to close as being off-topic due to the question being heavily dependent on personal circumstances/a university's policies, but I think that at the heart of this is a good question about using extracurriculars in general on grad applications. +1.